# Discrete spectrum of laplacian $ \sigma_{disc}(\Delta)$ on $ H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $\Delta: H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\subseteq L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$
be the Laplace operator in the weak sense.

What is the discrete spectrum of $\Delta$?

the discrete spectrum consists of isolated eigenvalues $ \lambda$ such that $\mathrm{ker}(\lambda-\Delta)$ is finite dimensional

Comment: Well taking Fourier transform, the Laplacian becomes multiplication by $|\xi|^2$, and its level sets all have Lebesgue measure zero, so doesn’t the spectrum consist of only the continuous part?

Comment: Because the point spectrum is empty... okay, thank you . That makes perfectly sense.